# Why do my asyncio network streams cause memory leaks on disconnect?

Tags: python, sockets, python-asyncio

I am currently trying to create an IRC client for personal uses.
My problem is the handling of connection losses. To test this I created a small test program that emulates constant reconnects:

```py
import asyncio

async def connect():
    while True:
        try:
            # never actually opens a connection
            reader, writer = await asyncio.open_connection("notahost", 1)
        except OSError as e:
            pass

asyncio.run(connect())
```

The issue that I found with this is that on every reconnect the memory usage of the process rises, why is that?
I've tried closing the writer afterwards but that results in an error because it is already dead.

Comment: Can you write an emulator for the *other side* and test what you are asking?

Comment: The question isn't really about testing and more about what makes the most sense, do I create "zombie" or "orphan" file descriptors if I just overwrite them or does it not matter since the asyncio library handles everything so handling it low level isn't even worth it.

Comment: It looks like you are facing the same issue described here: https://bugs.python.org/issue44697.